# split only 1 column to 2 but keeping others pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
 'unit': ['001 peds', '002 peds1', '003 4U', '004 4U1', '005 MS'],
 'N-D': ['Numerator', 'Denominator', 'Numerator', 'Denominator', 'Numerator'],
 'value': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],

}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

it looks like this:

```
    N-D       unit        value
Numerator     001 peds      0
Denominator   002 peds1     1
Numerator     003 4U        0
Denominator   004 4U1       1
Numerator     005 MS        0
```

I want to split the 'unit' column into 2 by a space : " "
my code:

```
df1 = df['unit'].str.split(" ", expand=True)
```

the output is:

```
  0      1
 001   peds
 002  peds1
 003     4U
 004    4U1
 005     MS
```

**but my other 2 columns are gone, I don't quite know the right syntax to do this on a dataframe level, so it will keep the rest of the columns.**

my desired output:

```
    N-D       0     1    value
Numerator     001  peds      0
Denominator   002  peds1     1
Numerator     003  4U        0
Denominator   004  4U1       1
Numerator     005  MS        0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
i = df.columns.get_loc('unit')
df2 = df['unit'].str.split(" ", expand=True)
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :i], df2, df.iloc[:, i+1:]], axis=1)

           N-D    0      1  value
0    Numerator  001   peds      0
1  Denominator  002  peds1      1
2    Numerator  003     4U      0
3  Denominator  004    4U1      1
4    Numerator  005     MS      0
```

---

If you want to get rid of the `0` column

```
df.assign(unit=df.unit.str.split(n=1).str[1])

           N-D   unit  value
0    Numerator   peds      0
1  Denominator  peds1      1
2    Numerator     4U      0
3  Denominator    4U1      1
4    Numerator     MS      0
```

You can rename the column `'unit'` whatever you like

```
df.assign(unit=df.unit.str.split(n=1).str[1]).rename(columns=dict(unit='w/e'))

           N-D    w/e  value
0    Numerator   peds      0
1  Denominator  peds1      1
2    Numerator     4U      0
3  Denominator    4U1      1
4    Numerator     MS      0
```

Comment: is there a more straight forward way? without having to use pd.concat? just wondering

Comment: @Jessica I can think of lots of ways... but not more straight forward.

Comment: how can I delete the column with '0' as name? del df3['0'] doesn't work. what's the actual column name?

Comment: @Jessica well, its `0` not `'0'`... but if you want to get rid of `0` then I have better solutions for you... one moment.

Comment: @piRsquared how would you do this if you have multiple columns to split and you would have to assign all the resulting columns back to your original df?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try:

> df[['unit','name']] = df.unit.str.split(" ",expand=True,)

> df

This will give you the required output.

```
N-D           unit name    value
Numerator     001  peds      0
Denominator   002  peds1     1
Numerator     003  4U        0
Denominator   004  4U1       1
Numerator     005  MS        0
```

Comment: this is not bad at all. Just need to drop the original column afterwards.